# How do I install an antivirus on Ubuntu Mate? [Failed]

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, lts, antivirus, ubuntu-mate

This is the error I get when attempting to install the 64-bit version for Ubuntu.

[image]

This is what I'm running:

[image]

On this machine:

[image]

Thus far, everything works flawlessly but I haven't been able to install an antivirus.

I've managed to install COMODO on my 32 bit version on a different device, but not here. I tried troubleshooting the software as well, to no avail.

[EDIT] Despite the fact that many of you do not run an antivirus, I want one for my own peace of mind.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but those "many" are correct. Please educate yourself on the topic. The only real application for an anti-virus on Linux is to scan Windows files before you send them up your network to Windows systems.

Comment: "I've managed to install COMODO on my 32 bit version on a different device, but not here. I tried troubleshooting the software as well, to no avail." is missing what went wrong for you for us to answer this. You install software with the Ubuntu software center. "clamtk" is in the repositories (and the default anti-virus application in Ubuntu). Does that install?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, clamtk seems to have worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: and again: you will only get false positives if you use it on Ubuntu.  Virus scanners on Linux are useless unless you need to scan Windows files before you send them to a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to have a virus scanner installed by the terms of use of the company you work for, to scan a Windows drive in your PC or to scan files you are going to send to other people and e-mail you are going to forward to other people, I suggest you install clamav. Is an open source antivirus engine for detecting trojans, viruses, malware & other malicious threats.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install clamav clamav-daemon clamtk clamtk-nautilus
freshclam
```

ClamTk is a GUI front-end for ClamAV, is designed to be an easy-to-use, on-demand scanner for Gnu/Linux systems.

**More Info:**

[Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV)